# Python Package depending on XML file

Tags: python, xml, pip

I created a private Python package that requires an XML file. When I run the package locally and on CircleCi, everything works great. Now, when I run code that installs the package as a dependency, I keep getting an error:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/venv-system/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/...../metadata_wsdl.xml'>
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong? I have not been able to figure this one out.

Comment: Are you installing/running your package outside of the virtualenv?  If yes, it's probably not going to work -- paths issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly include any resources that aren't Python source code (`*.py`) in your setuptools distribution.

There are several ways to do this. The one I'd recommend is to use a combination of `include_package_data = True` in your `setup()` function and a `MANIFEST.in` file.

So assuming your distribution is layed out as `my.package/my/package` (i.e., with no intermediate `src` or `lib` directory), you could use something along these lines:

**`setup.py`**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    packages = find_packages('my'),  # include all packages under my/

    include_package_data = True,     # include everything in source control
                                     # or included in MANIFEST.in
)
```

**`MANIFEST.in`**

```
recursive-include my *
recursive-include docs *
global-exclude *.pyc
global-exclude ._*
global-exclude *.mo
```

This would recursively include any type of file below `my.package/my/` as well as `my.package/docs/`, and globally exclude some other types of files unwanted in a released distribution.

Please refer to [Building and Distributing Packages with Setuptools » Including Data Files](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) for more details on the available methods to include data files, and [The MANIFEST.in template](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template) for more information about how to define your `MANIFEST`.

Once you've successfully included your data files in your distribution, you should make sure to use the [`ResourceManager` API](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) to access them from your code (as opposed to `__file__` trickery or other path hacks, which won't work for certain platforms or zipped eggs).

Comment: Great, glad I could help :-) Thanks for letting me know.